# Inheritance c++ Child Parent

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, parent

I have simple problem:

```
class Weapon{
public:
    int dmg;
    float speed;
    int rate;
};

class Uzi : public Weapon{
public:
    Uzi();
    void Shot(float angle);
};

Class Pistol : public Weapon{
public:
    Pistol();
    void Shot(float angle);
};
```

Later in code when I reserve for example:

```
Weapon wep;
wep = Uzi;
wep.Shot(15);
```

It doesn't work:
undefined reference to `Weapon::Shot(float)'

Can I reserve different type of 'wep' variable?
I think no because weapons are changing(pistol/uzi/...).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you added an implementation of the class in a cpp file?

Comment: Do you have, in fact, a definition for `Uzi::Shot`? And are you really trying to call `Shot()` without a parameter?

Comment: @MrLister I'm calling it with parameter, my bad when editing code for stack over flow.

Comment: I edited my answer, try the last snippet of code.

Comment: Your question was answered, but I'm curious. Why don't you just write `Uzi wep;`?

Comment: @MrLister Players weapon change over time, I don't want to declare new variable, I just want to change it to new weapon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Weapon wep;
wep = Uzi;
```

This is slicing. `Uzi` is-a `Weapon`, but not the other way around. You can use pointers for this:

```
Weapon* wep = new Uzi();
```

Also, you get the error because there is no `Shot()` method in the `Weapon()` class.

You might want to declare it `virtual` and also make it abstract (optional). You make it `virtual` to allow polymorphism.

That way:

```
Weapon* wep = new Uzi();
wep->Shot();
```

will call `Shot()` in the `Uzi` class, although it's called on a `Weapon` pointer.

The following should work:

```
class Weapon{
public:
    int dmg;
    float speed;
    int rate;
    virtual void Shot(float angle) {}; //move implementation to cpp file
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare `void Shot(float angle)` in the `Weapon` class.

Comment: I did but still getting undefined reference to `Weapon::Shot(float)'

Answer (score 0):

For polymorphism, you need to virtualise the method, Weapon should declare:

```
virtual void Shot(float angle) = 0;
```

and then each subclass should implement the virtual method.

Edit: Oh, and you can't just assign constructors to one another, you need to instantiate a concrete subclass, i.e:

```
Weapon *weapon = new Uzi();
```

as mentioned in several other answers.